# Disallow Ctrl-C Perl

Tags: perl

Is there a way to disallow the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> command to stop a script running in Perl.

I am aware of of the $SIG{'INT'} but I wanted to know for a way that if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is pressed the script would NOT stop no matter what.

At the moment I have:

```
$SIG{'INT'};
## for loop here
```

But once the for loop is over, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, the script will stop.

Comment: Please note that you should not edit other people's answers in order to interpolate comments.  You have enough rep to be able to leave comments anyway, but if you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and especially the section on [Reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation), you will see the comment 'you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you’ve asked, even with 1 rep'.

Comment: `$SIG{'INT'};` as a line of code by itself is meaningless, and if you had enabled [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) it would have told you so.

Comment: [perlfaq8: How do I trap Control Characters and Signals](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-trap-control-characters-signals-) and [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)

Answer (score 9):

[Ignore](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) interrupts completely:

```
$SIG{'INT'} = 'IGNORE';
```

Alternatively, map the interrupt to a different character - DEL maybe; then <kbd>Control-C</kbd> no longer generates an interrupt (or any other signal) and is a 'normal' control character.

Answer (score 1):

Catch `SIGINT` and simply ignore it. Would that not work? What's wrong with that? I didn't quite understand your meaning by saying that you're *aware* of what `$SIG{'INT'}` is.